# Каким образом работают рекурсивные вызовы

Tags: golang, рекурсия

Пытаюсь осилить рекурсию.
Задача: вывести все цифры числа в прямом порядке через пробел или другой разделитель, используя только целочисленную арифметику и рекурсию. Сторонние пакеты НЕЛЬЗЯ.
Я написал придумал такое решение:

```
package main

func main() {
    rec(198, 0)
}

func rec(n, m int) (int, int) {
    if n == 0 {
        //убрать лишний ноль в конце перевернутого числа
        m /= 10
        //завершить выполнение когда все цифры числа будут выведены.
        if m == 0 {
            //функция перестает вызываться рекурсивно, когда все цифры выведены в прямом,
            //по отношению к начальному числу, порядке.
            return 0, 0
        }
        //вывести остаток от деления m на 10. Получаем последнюю цифру перевернутого числа
        print(m%10, " ")
        //убрать ту цифру которую уже вывели.
        m /= 10
    }
    //рекурсивный переворот начального числа(делается в первую очередь)
    //когда все разряды прибавлены к m и умножены на 10,
    //получаем не цифры в обратном порядке, а именно перевернутое число.
    //но в конце у него будет 0, его потом убираем внутри n==0 && m!=0
    m += n % 10
    //запускаем функцию с аргментом без последней цифры начального числа,
    //которую уже включили в перевернутое число
    //m умножаем на 10, как раз чтобы получить не просто цифры в обратном порядке а именно число.
    //когда число будет переврнуто и функция провалится в условие n==0 && m!=0
    //функция будет вызываться так же рекурсивно но с 0 в качестве обоих аргументов.
    return rec(n/10, m*10)
}
```

Но у меня есть подозрение, что можно сделать как то без той части условия, где n=0 && m!=0.
Но пока что не пойму как.
Подскажите пожалуйста, если знаете.

UPD:

```
package main


func main() {
    rec(123456789098765432)
    println()
}

func rec(n int) {
    if n < 10 {
        print(n)
    } else {
        rec(n / 10)
        print(" ", n%10)
    }
}
```

в этом подходе результат рекурсивных вызовов работает по принципу стека чтоли? LIFO? Во первых принты не выполняются при каждом else а сначала вызываются все экземпляры функции `rec()` а уже потом происходит вывод, но вывод  происходит в обратном порядке по отношению к вызовам `rec()` но если выводы поставить перед вызовом `rec()`, то порядок вывода будет прямой по отношению к вызовам, но обратный по отношению к начальному числу.

Comment: Не else работает цикл, а вызов функцией самой себя (это можно представить как переход на начало функции)

Comment: Стек вызовов работает как стек (LIFO), внезапно. Сначала вы входите внутрь рекурсивных вызовов, потом в обратном порядке из них выходите. В обратном порядке - потому что стек вызовов - это стек.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекурсивный алгоритм проектируется так:

- определить окончание рекурсии
- определиться с порядком действий: сначала обрабатываем элемент, затем передаём дальше по цепочке, или сначала обрабатываем цепочку, и только затем выполняем действие над элементом.

В вашем случае окончание рекурсии - число, состоящее из одной цифры. С ним можно сделать только одно - напечатать его и вернуть управление.

Теперь про действия. Если в числе больше одной цифры, то удобно вы можете извлечь только крайнюю правую, взяв остаток от деления на 10. Это и есть тот элемент, над которым выполняется действие - печать с разделителем. Но печатать вам нужно слева направо, поэтому с порядком тоже понятно - сначала рекурсия, которая напечатает цифры слева, и только затем печатаем крайнюю правую цифру.

Получается вот какая функция:

```go
// Печатает цифры числа с разделителем `delim` между цифрами.
// Печатает в `os.Stdout`
func print_digits(n uint, delim string) {
    if n < 10 {
        // Самая левая цифра, перед ней не печатаем разделитель
        fmt.Print(n)
    } else {
        // Печатаем цифры слева
        print_digits(n/10, delim)
        // Печатаем разделитель и крайнюю правую цифру
        fmt.Print(delim, n%10)
    }
}
```

Сначала проверяем, завершена ли рекурсия: `if n < 10 {}`. Рекурсия у нас заканчивается в самой левой цифре, поэтому разделитель не печатаем:

```go
    if n < 10 {
        // Самая левая цифра, перед ней не печатаем разделитель
        fmt.Print(n)
    }
```

Теперь тело рекурсии:

```go
        // Печатаем цифры слева
        print_digits(n/10, delim)
        // Печатаем разделитель и крайнюю правую цифру
        fmt.Print(delim, n%10)
```

Проверка для чисел 1 (разделитель -), 10 (разделитель +) и 123 (разделитель /): https://go.dev/play/p/eXps2XXKLqO

```
1
1+0
1/2/3
```

Работает ))

PS. На самом деле есть ещё третий вариант рекурсии - сначала делаем половину действия, вызываем рекурсию, и после выполняем вторую половину. Но в вашем случае это не требуется.

Comment: Да уж. Совсем теперь запутался в рекурсии..Почему рекурсивные вызовы в обратном порядке?

Comment: @Quester Рекурсивных вызовов в обратном порядке нет - вызов ведь всего один, а печатаем  цифру после вызова, когда левые цифры уже выведены

Comment: @MBo как же один, ведь на каждое `n/10` рекурсивный вызов происходит пока число не станет одноразрядным?

Comment: отредактировал вопрос, добавил к нему еще один на основе ответов.

Comment: @Quester да, когда рекурсия вызывается до обработчика элемента, это LIFO - первый элемент, самая правая цифра, обрабатывается в самую последнюю очередь. Элементы перебираются в обратном порядке. Если рекурсия вызывается после обработки элемента, то это FIFO - элементы обрабатываются в том же порядке, в каком перебираются.

Comment: а обрботчик элемента в данном случае это `print(n%10)` ?

Comment: `n%10` извлекает элемент, а `print` его обрабатывает. Соответственно, `n/10` извлекает "хвост" рекурсии, список оставшихся элементов

Answer (score 2):

Что-то вы намудрили:

```
func main() {
      print_digits(1023)
}

func print_digits(n int) {
    if (n>9) {
        print_digits(n/10)
    }   
    fmt.Print(n%10, " ")
}

>> 1 0 2 3
```